# How can I call a function in command line on Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to write a calculator on a text editor and then call the function with the parameters in Node.js command line. (node index.js sub 3 2 1)
My function has to have a list of numbers (min 2).
This is my function that I wrote to subtract the numbers:

```
function sub() {
var d = 0;
for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    d = d + (arguments[i] - arguments[i+1]);
}
return d;}
```

My question is how i call this function on the command line and show the result.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
 var sub = console.log(process.argv[sub]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse your parameters. `process.argv` is a numerical array, it 
 contains only integer indexes.

To keep it simple you can just write this:

```
if(process.argv[2] === 'sub') {
  sub()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be as simple as, suppose following is *calculator.js*:

```
function calc (op1, op2, operation) {
    if (operation === 'sum' || operation === 'add'){
        return op1 + op2;
    }
    else if (operation === 'sub'){
        return op1 - op2;
    }
    else if (operation === 'mul'){
        return op1 * op2;
    }
    else if (operation === 'div'){
        return op1 / op2;
    }
    // expand here more operations if needed
    return 'Not sure what to do!';
}

var result = calc(Number(process.argv[3]), Number(process.argv[4]), process.argv[2]);

console.log(result);
```

Now Run for addition as:

> node calculator.js add 1 2

Run for subtraction as:

> node calculator.js sub 1 2

**Same way you can pass command input to call file functions.**